# Efficient tabulation of variables, grouped by different names

Tags: dataframe, frequency

I have a data frame of genus names (~1.4 million entries), with multiple entries of each genus. Each occurrence of each genus has an assigned environment - terrestrial or marine - and some genera will be present in both environments. Is there an efficient solution to tabulating the marine and/or terrestrial occurrences for each genus name (~70,000 unique names), e.g.

| genus | environment |
| --- | --- |
| Tax1 | Marine |
| Tax1 | Marine |
| Tax2 | Terrestrial |
| Tax3 | Marine |
| Tax1 | Terrestrial |
| Tax3 | Marine |

Tax1: Marine = 2, Terrestrial = 1

Tax2: Terrestrial = 1

Tax3: Marine = 2

I only know of table, but I can't see a way to get it to work on a factor-type basis

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick.

```
for i in set(df['genus']): 

    temp_df = df[df['genus'] == i] #makes a temporary df with each value in genus
    sub_level = dict(temp_df['environment'].value_counts()) #contains dictionary of elements and their counts

    for j,k in zip(sub_level.keys() , sub_level.values()) :
           print(i , " - " , j ," = " , k)
```

Output :

```
Tax1  -  Marine  =  2
Tax1  -  Terrestrial  =  1
Tax3  -  Marine  =  2
Tax2  -  Terrestrial  =  1
```